# Multiplying Lists through Folding

Tags: ocaml

So I am currently trying to figure out how to write a function where it takes 2 lists of equal lengths and multiplies the same position of both lists through folding, and returns the result as a new List.

```
eg) let prodList [1; 2; 3] [4; 5; 6] ;; 
==> (through folding) ==> [1*4; 2*5; 3*6]
==> result = [4; 10; 18]
```

I feel like I need to use List.combine, since it will put the values that need to be multiplied into tuples. After that, I can't figure out how to break apart the tuple in a way that allows me to multiply the values. Here is what I have so far:

```
let prodLists l1 l2 =
  let f a x =  (List.hd(x)) :: a in
  let base = [] in
  let args = List.rev (List.combine l1 l2) in
  List.fold_left f base args
```

Am I on the right track?

Comment: Why through folding?

Comment: It's just a requirement I can't argue against.

Comment: Well, what you're doing here is a `map` operation, so I guess you get to implement `map` as a fold.

Comment: That makes sense, it gives me the ability to apply a function to each tuple, but there is still the issue of multiplication. Unless there's a function that breaks and multiples the data within each tuple, but does that exist?

Comment: Isn't that just something like `fn (x, y) -> x * y`? Not sure about OCaml syntax.

Comment: The function is suppose to be more generic. It should run for [x1, y1, ..., n1] [x2, y2, ..., n2]. So the lengths of both lists can vary, but they have to be equal to each other. From what I understand, what you proposed would only work for lists that have a length of 2, or am I overthinking it?

Comment: No, you'd use `combine` to get a list of tuples, then `map` that function (which takes a 2-tuple) over the list.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `fold_left2` which folds two lists of the same length. The documentation can give you more details (https://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/List.html):

```
val fold_left2 : ('a -> 'b -> 'c -> 'a) -> 'a -> 'b list -> 'c list -> 'a
```

`List.fold_left2 f a [b1; ...; bn] [c1; ...; cn]` is `f (... (f (f a b1 c1) b2 c2) ...) bn cn`. Raise `Invalid_argument` if the two lists are determined to have different lengths.

Another way is to fold the output of combine as you have suggested, I would recommend you to try it by yourself before looking at the solution bellow.

Solution:

```
let prod_lists l s =
  List.rev (List.fold_left2 (fun acc a b -> (a * b) :: acc) [] l s);;

let prod_lists' l s =
  List.fold_left (fun acc (a, b) -> (a * b) :: acc) [] (List.rev (List.combine l s));;
```

Answer (score 0):

First let me note using fold to implement this operation seems a bit forced, since you have to traverse both lists at the same time. Fold however combines the elements of a single list. Nonetheless here is an implementation.

```
let e [] = []

let f x hxs (y::ys) = (x*y) :: hxs ys 

let prodList xs ys = List.fold_right f xs e ys
```

Looks a bit complicated, so let me explain.

**Universal Property of fold right**

First you should be aware of the following property of `fold_right`.

```
h xs = fold_right f xs e
```

if and only if

```
h [] = e
h (x::xs) = f x (h xs)
```

This means that if we write the multiplication of lists in the recursive form below, then we can use the `e` and `f` to write it using fold as above. Note though we are operating two lists so `h` takes two arguments.

**Base case - empty lists**

Multiplying two empty lists returns an empty list.

```
h [] [] = []
```

How to write this in the form above? Just abstract over the second argument.

```
h [] = fun [] -> []
```

So,

```
e = fun [] -> []`
```

Or equivalently,

```
e [] = []
```

**Recursive case - non-empty lists**

```
h (x::xs) (y::ys) = x*y :: h xs ys
```

Or, using just one argument,

```
h (x::xs) = fun -> (y::ys) -> x*y :: h xs ys
```

Now we need to rewrite this expression in the form `h (x::xs) = f x (h xs)`. It may seem complicated but we just need to abstract over `x` and `h xs`.

```
h (x::xs) = (fun x hxs -> fun (y::ys) -> x*y :: hxs ys) x (h xs)
```

so we have that `f` is defined by,

```
f = fun x hxs -> fun (y::ys) -> x*y :: hxs ys
```

or equivalently,

```
f x hxs (y::ys) = x*y :: hxs ys
```

**Solution as a fold right**

Having determined both `e` and `f` we just plug then into fold according to the first equation of the property above. And we get,

```
h xs = List.fold_right f xs e
```

or equivalently,

```
h xs ys = List.fold_right f xs e ys
```

**Understanding the implementation**

Note that the type of `List.fold_right f xs e` is `int list -> int list`, so the fold is building a function on lists, that given some `ys` will multiply it with the given parameter `xs`.

For an empty `xs` you will expect an empty `ys` and return an empty result so,

```
e [] = fun [] -> []
```

As for the recursive case, the function `f` in a `fold_right` must implement a solution for `x::xs` from a solution for `xs`. So `f` takes an  `x` of type `int` and a function `hxs` of type `int list -> int list` which implements the multiplication for the tail, and it must implement multiplication for `x::xs`.

```
f x hxs = fun (y::ys) -> x*y :: hxs ys
```

So `f` constructs a function that multiplies `x` with `y`, and then applies to `ys` the already constructed `hxs` which multiplies `xs` to a list.

Answer (score 0):

You mostly have the right idea; you'll want to `combine` (`zip` in other languages) the two lists and then `map` over each tuple:

```
let prod_lists l1 l2 =
  List.combine l1 l2
  |> List.map (fun (a, b) -> a * b)
```

The key is that you can pattern match on that tuple using `(a, b)`.

You can also `fold` over the combined list, then `rev` the result, if you don't want to use `map`.

Answer (score 0):

The trick any time you want to use a fold is usually asking, "what is my accumulator?" because it's the only state you can pass from one iteration to the next.

If the accumulator is just the resulting list, then we don't really have a way to deal with the second list, *but* if our accumulator is a tuple of the accumulated list and the second list, then one each iteration we can update the accumulator but *also* the second list.

```
# let lst1 = [1;2;3] in
  let lst2 = [4;5;6] in
  List.fold_left (fun (acc, y::ys) x -> (x * y :: acc, ys)) ([], lst2) lst1;;

Line 3, characters 15-57:
Warning 8 [partial-match]: this pattern-matching is not exhaustive.
Here is an example of a case that is not matched:
(acc, [])

Line 3, characters 15-57:
Warning 8 [partial-match]: this pattern-matching is not exhaustive.
Here is an example of a case that is not matched:
(acc, [])

- : int list * int list = ([18; 10; 4], [])
```

- There are a bunch of warnings here about non-exhaustive matching. We can ignore this, because you've already specified the lists are of equal length.
- We get both lists as our final result. That's okay.
- The built-up list is backwards. This is also okay. We can reverse it.

If we look at this recursion:

```
List.fold_left (fun (acc, y::ys) x -> (x * y :: acc, ys)) ([], [4;5;6]) [1;2;3]

List.fold_left (fun (acc, y::ys) x -> (x * y :: acc, ys)) (4 :: [], [5;6]) [2;3]

List.fold_left (fun (acc, y::ys) x -> (x * y :: acc, ys)) (10 :: 4 :: [], [6]) [3]

List.fold_left (fun (acc, y::ys) x -> (x * y :: acc, ys)) (18 :: 10 :: 4 :: [], []) []

([18; 10; 4], [])
```

Correcting the latter two issues above with `fst` and `List.rev`:

```
# let lst1 = [1;2;3] in
  let lst2 = [4;5;6] in
  List.fold_left (fun (acc, y::ys) x -> (x * y :: acc, ys)) ([], lst2) lst1 
  |> fst 
  |> List.rev;;

Line 3, characters 15-57:
Warning 8 [partial-match]: this pattern-matching is not exhaustive.
Here is an example of a case that is not matched:
(acc, [])

Line 3, characters 15-57:
Warning 8 [partial-match]: this pattern-matching is not exhaustive.
Here is an example of a case that is not matched:
(acc, [])

- : int list = [4; 10; 18]
```

And if we want to avoid the warnings we can handle that empty list case by raising an exception.

```
# let lst1 = [1;2;3] in
  let lst2 = [4;5;6] in
  List.fold_left 
    (fun (acc, lst) x -> 
       match lst with
       | [] -> invalid_arg "unequal length lists" 
       | y::ys -> (x * y :: acc, ys)) 
    ([], lst2) 
    lst1
  |> fst
  |> List.rev;;
- : int list = [4; 10; 18]
```

And thus we can see that this task can be readily solved using a fold, if we're a bit creative about the accumulator.